# Is there a modern auth solution for the OAB Offline Address Book?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, authentication

we find that when basic authentication is blocked at Exchange Online level, Outlook clients cannot download the OAB. We can enable the basic auth for OAB access which works, but is there a way to have Outlook use modern auth to download the OAB, or is it yet to come?

Comment: The Exchange server needs to enable `AllowBasicAuthOfflineAddressBook` via PowerShell. See [link1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/disable-basic-authentication-in-exchange-online) and [link2](https://office365itpros.com/2018/10/24/disable-basic-authentication-exchange-online/).

Comment: yes I actually made the point we can do that in my question - but I'm asking when Outlook will use modern authenciation to access the OAB - seeing as basic auth will be deprecated soon.  The MS articles are a little vague around OAB functionality.  This article https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-february-2021-update/ba-p/2111904  states "If EWS has Basic Auth disabled, Outlook won’t use Basic Auth for any of the other protocols or endpoints it needs to access."  But for OAB we get error 0x80190197 due to Basic Auth being disabled.

Comment: If you have enabled Modern Auth, OAB should work.

Comment: You are correct @harrymc - in this case although not 100% proven, it was working outside the corporate environment.  So it was likely outbound proxy preventing the modern connection to OAB.